# Does weblogic support CDI Beans?

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, weblogic11g

I started to work with weblogic 11g version 10.3.2.0

Does weblogic support CDI Beans ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't work out of the box, but with [Apache OpenWebBeans](http://openwebbeans.apache.org/) (the CDI implementation of Apache) you can get WebLogic there. Their JIRA shows that they worked on it and fixed it. If there's a problem, I would ask them directly. The documentation isn't very detailed, but as I see they respond quickly to questions. And MyFaces CODI also lists WebLogic as a [compatible server](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/EXTCDI/Intro#Intro-Servers) if you are using OpenWebBeans, so I think they tested it carefully.

Answer (score 1):

At this time, only JBoss AS 6 and Glassfish 3 support CDI Beans. CDI only works in Java EE 6 appservers.

Comment: +1, but it _is_ possible to make it run in any environment. You just won't be getting all the features I guess.

Comment: Out of the box, CDI also works in Caucho Resin. CDI itself (e.g. by using Weld) can be added to most every environment.

Comment: @Chen Checkout the JEE 6 Tutorial from Oracle Website

Comment: Pete Muir, lead of Weld, says that Weld (RI for JSR299) can be used in Servlet Containers and JSE also: http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/Weld110FinalAvailable. I don't know if has other implementation that supports this.